# Image isn't rendered with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a method for upload a image to the server using Server.MapPath and HttpPostedFileBase, this work great, the image is uploaded but when I try to use the tag

```
<div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal1">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="@Url.Content(item.ImagenPortada)" alt="Image" />
                    @*<img class="img-fluid rounded" src="@item.ImagenPortada" alt="...">*@
                </a>                    
                <div class="portfolio-caption">
                    <h4>@item.Titulo</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">@item.Descripcion</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Any suggestions? Ty!

Comment: Is item.ImagenPortada a relative path? Eg. is it `"~/images/image.jpg"` ?

Comment: I saved two images, one with relative path and other with absolute path. Neither works, because in the view, the debugger don't read the <img> tag, but it do with the h3 and p tags. I don't know why its skipping the <img> tag.

Comment: Now I realize one important thing. I'm saving the image in one project different from where I'm showing the image. I'm uploading the image in the admin panel (ISAdministrationMVC) and using the tag img in (ISPresentationMVC). So the image who have the relative path is impossible to show, but I dont know why the image with absolute path isn't showing.

Comment: You are saying two different projects? Then how can server map path between two different projects? Are you storing the images in a common location (e.g. C:\test\img.jpg)? In that case you will have to map the path every time you render the images. Relative or absolute paths cannot navigate outside the project folder unless done by codes.

Comment: inspect and Check whether the path is showing correct.it should work @iMSn20

Comment: @iMSn20 How are you storing your paths? Can you show us that bit?